# Model Won't Train (Loss Doesn't Move)

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

**TL;DR**: I can't find my mistake when using the Tensorflow optimizer to train an extremely small neural net. The loss either doesn't move or moves once then gets stuck (it seems to really like the value 0.693147 which is ln(2)...).

**Issue and Code:** I'm trying to implement the 12-net part of the cascade classifier in Li et al ([here](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~xsh835/assets/cvpr2015_cascnn.pdf)) in Tensorflow. It's an extremely simple net, but nothing I try seems to get it training.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import cv2
import numpy as np


input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 12, 12, 3])
input_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, shape=[1, 2])
conv_1 = slim.conv2d(input_tensor, 16, (3, 3), scope='conv1')
pool_1 = slim.max_pool2d(conv_1, (3, 3), 2, scope='pool1')
flatten = slim.flatten(pool_1)
fully_con = slim.fully_connected(flatten, 16, scope='full_con')
fully_con_2 = slim.fully_connected(fully_con, 2, scope='output')
probs = tf.nn.softmax(fully_con_2)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=input_label, logits=fully_con_2))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.001).minimize(loss)
```

This defines the net. It takes in a (for now, single) 12x12 image and label, does a single 3x3 convolution with stride 1 and 16 filters, a 3x3 max pool with stride 2, then fully connects to 16 features, and finally makes a binary classification. I am able to perform a forward pass through the code, so I don't think the issue is here. This is my training loop - I have 3 12x12 images (2 faces, 1 tree) and just alternately feed them to the optimizer (clearly not best training practice, but I'm just trying to get it to work):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    im = cv2.imread('resized.jpg').reshape(1, 12, 12, 3).astype('float16')
    im2 = cv2.imread('resized2.jpg').reshape(1, 12, 12, 3).astype('float16')
    im3 = cv2.imread('resize3.jpg').reshape(1, 12, 12, 3).astype('float16')
    im_lab_1 = np.array([[0, 1]], dtype='float16')
    im_lab_2 = np.array([[0, 1]], dtype='float16')
    im_lab_3 = np.array([[1, 0]], dtype='float16')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={input_tensor: im3, input_label: im_lab_3}))
        for i in range(50000):
            if i % 3 == 0:
                # _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed1)
                # print(l)
                optimizer.run(feed_dict={input_tensor: im, input_label: im_lab_1})
            elif i % 4 == 0:
                # _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed2)
                # print(l)
                optimizer.run(feed_dict={input_tensor: im2, input_label: im_lab_2})
            elif i % 5 == 0:
                optimizer.run(feed_dict={input_tensor: im3, input_label: im_lab_3})
        print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={input_tensor: im3, input_label: im_lab_3}))
```

I've tried both `optimizer.run(...)` and the commented out `sess.run([optimizer, loss]...)`. The first `sess.run(loss...)` seems to spit out something correct, but after that, the loss gets stuck and never moves again. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With so few activations, my guess is they all get stuck. Try setting `activation_fn=None` on all of the layers (i.e. make it linear). Layers add ReLUs by default. Even once you've finished debugging, some of these look like they should be linear.

Comment: Allen, I tried your solution, and the same issue is occurring - I also tried changing the activation functions to PReLU and adding dropout, neither of which seem to do anything. I also tried making batches of the images, and there is still no movement on the loss after the first iteration. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Not sure it's the main issue, but the image feeding logic is a bit off. Looks like it should be `if i % 3 == 0:`, `elif i % 3 == 1:`, `elif i % 3 == 2:`?